# Does Android Studio supports AngularJS for Android UI design?

Tags: android, angularjs, android-studio

I have a question about Android Studio: Does AS supports AngularJS code while designing XML files, e.g. for small animations or effects?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**SUMMARY : NO**

There is no way you can write Angular JS code while developing Android Native app. You can use Angular in a WebView (using js/html so), that's all.

Comment: So we only design android UI in xml?

Comment: @SumitPathak if you don't use a framework : yes. Probably some hybrid framework like Ionic will help you more, but you are loosing the native app

Comment: Material design is the only way to do better UI ,, don't go with 3rd parties

Answer (score 8):

AngularJS is a completely different technology than what is used in native Android apps. Native Android apps use Java and/or C for their code, which is compiled when you build the app. AngularJS is a framework for web development, running specifically on Javascript (a completely different technology than Java).

You can build apps without using native Java or C code, but there are tradeoffs. As noted in other answers, you can display webpage views as apps (using technologies like [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/)]), or use frameworks like [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) to write code in Javascript that then gets compiled to a native app. You could use AngluarJS in the webview instance, since it just displays a webpage, however not in something like React Native. I highly encourage you to check both of these (and other options) out, but keep in mind that they have their own limitations and tradeoffs – no one way is the "right" way to build an app.

In summary: No, AngularJS is a web technology, not a native app technology.

Answer (score 0):

new answer = Yes... Sort of, you can do it with:

https://www.nativescript.org/

It translates javascript, angular and typescript code into native components!

Apparantly it's possible to use nativescript in Android Studio with:

https://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/android/getting-started/hello-world

Answer (score -1):

Android Does not support AngularJs. but still if you want to use you can use it in webview.